# how to properly override CSS in external file

Tags: css, xhtml

There's a lot of questions that look like this one but none really answer the problem I have.

My situation is a follows:

I have the need to change the display of a lot of elements so that they show properly in the page and the semantics are correct.
I somewhat have the js version and the nojs version. Some elements exist to be seen only when the user is using js and others are only meant to be seen when js is turned off.

I have selectores that have a nice specificity (don't argue, they really do make sense in the context, I just changed the classes here in order not to let go where the original code is)

```
.imagesContainer div.imageContainer  .imagedata
```

And then this element is meant to be hidden when the user does not have js. So I did something like:

```
.nojs{
    display:none;
}
```

I tried it in in the same file as the HTML is expecting that the priority would be external file < same file < inline. But seems like what is now is external file = same file < inline (no priority between the external file and inline).

What's the best way to deal with this problem?

Changing the specificity of the first selector I've shown is no solution.
I'd also rather not to place the CSS inline. It's a pain, takes too much space in the markup and makes it harder to read.
I'd also prefer not to use !important. It's considered not to be a correct way to solve this kind of problem and I agree.
I'm using XHTML so noscript tag is not defined in the DTD (I need to use XHTML according to rules to which I am subjected to),

Comment: Can you show the HTML to go with this? Where is the `nojs` class being used?

Comment: @Pekka .nojs is used in so many places scattered through the HTML that I'd have to give you a ton load of HTML. The .js and .nojs is in about 1/4 of the HTML elements in the page.

Comment: `<noscript>` **is** defined in the XHTML DTD...

Comment: Yeah... seems like it, but it is not defined in the DTD for the head, according to my research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... how to solve this problem... It was not that easy but with the help of the w3c and your answers I was able to get to a proper result.

After trying multiple paths of possibly solving this (including adding a style or a link tag programmaticly), I got an answer to what I needed.
In order to do this the easiest way, you need to have, at least, 2 style sheets. One for this system and the other as your "regular" style sheet (the one with all the CSS of your page).

Then place .nojs class to all (x)HTML elements you want to make appear only when the user is not using js and .js for the elements you want to make appear only when the user is using js.

Place the following in this system's style sheet:

```
.js{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Then use this js code to be executed after the  is complete. Preferably when the DOMContentLoaded event is dispached.

```
var jsNojsStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[1]; // change this index depending on your needs
if(jsNojsStyleSheet.deleteRule){
    jsNojsStyleSheet.deleteRule(0);
    jsNojsStyleSheet.insertRule('.nojs{ display:none !important; }', 0);
}else{
    // IE8 has his own way of dealing with this situation
    jsNojsStyleSheet.removeRule(0);
    jsNojsStyleSheet.addRule('.nojs', 'display:none !important', 0);
}
```

Don't forget to change the index in the list depending on your needs.

Now you are good to go and test this.
This is supposed to remove the .js rule and insert the .nojs rule, replacing the previous one.

This is, for me, the cleanest way of doing this job. Any critics or improvements to this technique are welcome.

Note: IE requires you to do something to refresh the parsong of the page. I used a code that toggles the checked of a checkbox twice, be creative and find your own solution to this.

Edit:
I also found out that this is much faster and does not have the flicking unlike other techniques that used jQuery and whatnot to solve this problem. All changes are made using the browser's own adaption to changes when CSS changes and not changing each HTML node 1 by 1.

This system work with IE8, not sure about IE7, though.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have a `display` property already set for `.imagesContainer div.imageContainer  .imagedata` then simply adding `nojs` to the element isnt going to override because of specificty. Youd have to:

`.imagesContainer div.imageContainer  .imagedata.nojs { display: none; }`

Or whatever element `nojs` is added to.

If i were you i would completely reverse this. For the elements that do not display without js enabled i would set them to `display: none` by default. Then berfor any styles/links or other scripts in the head i would use some js to assing `js` to the `body` or `html` element. Then in the css i would change the display property with `.js <the rest of the selector>` for the elements to be shown.

Comment: I don't want to apply only to that element. It's a nice amount of elements that I really don't know the number. The page has many different versions depending on the user (php preprocesses the page) and there are many elements that need to come and go depending on whether the user has js or not... That's not a solution that is actually makeable

Comment: Actually... There are elements that are meant to be inline-block, others are block, others are inline... It's not that easy to reverse... Any other solution?

Comment: using `display: auto` will override and revert it to the default i think. But either way youll need to increase the specificity of the selector for `.nojs` so it is equal to or greater than the with js one.

Comment: I'll let this question sleep on the subject for the night. I'll also sleep on this this night. Maybe I can come up with a proper solution for this problem. Oh! And setting display auto with js is not the solution :(

Comment: `then simply adding nojs to the element isnt going to override because of specificty.` this.

Comment: +1. This can be a solution for ppl who don't have restrictions like I have.

Answer (score 2):

As @prodigitalson correctly notes, your `nojs` class is always going to be less specific than your detailed class definitions.

As far as I can see, `!important` is indeed the only way to achieve what you want to do without creating a whole lot of class definitions with more specificity.

Arguably, cases like this are what `!important` was originally designed for, and where it is totally okay to use it. `!important` becomes problematic where it is misused to override specificity because you can't figure out how to reach the required specificity the "right" way.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the idea. Thanks to you I got more easily to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity for the exact way to calculate specifity.

According to this section:

```
count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
```

Your specifity for `.imagesContainer div.imageContainer  .imagedata` is 0031 (0 no inline, 0 no id, 3 classes, 1 element). You have to overtrump this number to overwrite the display.

Let's assume your `body` tag would look like this `<body id="foobar">` this should overwrite the display setting on your example element:

```
#foobar .nojs { display: none; }
```

because it's specifity is 0110 and 110 is bigger than 31. (0 no inline, 1 id, 1 class, 0 elements)

(Not that I neccesairly advocate id'ing your body tag, this is merely an example of selector nesting that would overwrite your css selector you gave)

Edit:
See this fiddle for a more specific solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KAuAx/

Comment: I tried that this morning :D. Didn't work. I was unable to override that properly with js. I think I got a better solution. I'll post that and then we'll try to vote it down or up

Comment: I'm tring a better approach. O have an approach but I don't know if it's really a good one. Pls wait.

Comment: "I was unable to override that properly with js." but you are not overwriting it with javascript, but with css and classes that are present or not when loading the page.

Comment: You solved the problem one way, but you didn't give the answer to undo when the js is executing. Check my answer and see if it makes sense ;).

Comment: I think you are going about the problem the wrong way around. See the link in my edit. Don't add style via javascript, but assume no-javascript, and with javascript, disable no-javascript elements.

Comment: Let's see... Personally, I always prefer not to use libraries. I only use libraries for hard stuff, so... -1 on that. What you are stating that I'm doing, is wrongly interpreted. Check if I explained properly, and if not, please suggest improvements. For the last one: messing with the DOM, specially using a library like jQuery is way, way slower than my solution. You are also messing up with the HTML which is also not wanted here unless really needed.